# How to predict when the next event occurs, based on times of previous events?

Tags: probability, modeling, data-mining, predictive-models

I'm a high school student and I'm working on a computer programming project, but I don't have a lot of experience in statistics and modeling data beyond a high school statistics course so I'm kinda confused.

Basically, I have a reasonably large list (assume it's large enough to meet the assumptions for any statistical tests or measures) of times that someone decided to print a document. Based on this list, I would like to construct a statistical model of some sort that will predict the most likely time for the next print job given all of the previous event times.

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758036/predict-next-event-occurrence-based-on-past-occurrences), but the responses don't exactly help out with what I have in mind for my project. I did some additional research and found that a [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) would likely allow me to do so accurately, but I can't find a link on how to generate a Hidden Markov Model using just a list of times. I also found that using a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) on the list may be useful but basically, I'd like to get some more information about it from someone who's actually used them and knows their limitations and requirements before just trying something and hoping it works.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: +1 This is a well-articulated, well thought out question, Ankush.  I hope you get some great responses.  Welcome to our site!

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title -- I was moving words around to try to make things more coherent and I guess I ended up making it not make sense at all! Hopefully someone with the appropriate knowledge can help.

Answer (score 11):

Hidden Markov models would apply if the data were random emissions from some underlying unobserved Markov model; I wouldn't rule that out, but it doesn't seem a very natural model.

I would think about [point processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process), which match your particular data well.  There is a great deal of work on predicting earthquakes (though I don't know much about it) and even [crime](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/16/us/16police.html).

If there are many different people printing, and you're just seeing the times but not the individual identities, a Poisson process might work well (the superposition of multiple independent point processes is approximately Poisson), though it would have to be inhomogeneous (the chance of a point varies over time): people are less likely to be printing at 3am than at 3pm.

For the [inhomogeneous Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-homogeneous_Poisson_process) model, the key would be getting a good estimate of the chance of a print job at a particular time on a particular day.

If these print times are for students in a classroom, though, it could be quite tricky, as they're not likely to be independent and so the Poisson process wouldn't work well.

[Here's a link to a paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~mbshort/papers/crime2.pdf) on the crime application.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know of any way to create a model for a point process? It seems to be the most relevant, but I'm not well-versed in statistics so it all seems confusing (Poisson vs Determinantal vs Cox?) when I'm reading wikipedia... :-\

Comment: @Unk - I would start by making some plots of the data. How long is this list of print times?

Comment: It's about a year's worth of data. I'll make some plots and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the predicting the likely time using multivariate Bayesian  scan statistic (MBSS) could be of assistance. This MBSS has advantage of improving the timeliness and accuracy of event detection.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Esan. Can you say more about MBSS, how it works, and how it would help?